# attr_reader with question mark in a name

Tags: ruby

Sorry for this, probably, really newbie question:

I want to define a getter that returns bool value. f.i.:

```
  attr_reader :server_error?
```

But then, how do I update it, as Ruby (1.9) throws syntax error if there is a question mark at the end:

```
#unexpected '='
@server_error? = true
self.server_error? = true
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest defining your own method rather than using `:attr_reader`

```
def server_error?
  !!@server_error # Or any other idiom that you generally use for checking boolean
end
```

for brevity's sake, you could do it in one line:

```
def server_error?; !!@server_error; end
```

Answer (score 42):

This question is old but with `alias_method` you can achieve that:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :server_error
  alias_method :server_error?, :server_error

  # [...]
end
```

Basically the method `server_error?` will be an alias for the `server_error` method.

Comment: I'd expect Foo#server_error to return an error or ar error message, not a boolean.

Comment: This technique exposes both `:server_error` and `:server_error?` as public methods, which may not be desirable.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to define such methods repeatedly, define a *module* named `AttrBoolean`:

```
module AttrBoolean
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attr_boolean(*names)
      names.each do |name|
        define_method(:"#{name}=") do |value|
          instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", value)
        end

        define_method(:"#{name}?") do
          !!instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}")
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can use this in the following manner:

```
class Foo
  include AttrBoolean

  attr_boolean :server_error, :resolved
end

f = Foo.new
f.server_error = true
f.resolved = false
f.server_error? # => true
f.resolved?     # => false
```

Note that getter methods without question mark are not defined.
The expression `f.server_error` throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

similar to Swanand, I would propose to add a method. In Ruby 3 you can use endless method definitions for a little more elegance:

```rb
def server_error? = !!@server_error
```

Answer (score 0):

`attr_reader` is an example of what "Metaprogramming Ruby" calls a "Class Macro". If you wanted to, you could define your own class macro, such that you could do

```
Class SampleClass
  my_boolean_reader :server_error

  def initialize
    @server_error = false
  end
end

sample_object = SampleClass.new
sample_object.server_error? # => false
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your response. What exactly is my_boolean_reader here? I got NoMethodError, so obviously I am missing something.

Comment: @c64ification: I said you could define a method called `my_boolean_reader` that'd do what you were after.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm IMO this answer is incomplete unless you specify what `my_boolean_reader` is and how it should be defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rails or ActiveSupport you can do it like:

```
private

def server_error?
   @server_error.present?
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def server_error?
  !@server_error.nil?
end
```

As recommended by [Rubocop](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Style/DoubleNegation) since `!!` is a violation

Comment: N.B. this doesn't work if if `@server_error` is `false`.